# Windows Powershell Hello World not printing

Tags: function, powershell

I have a script. Saved it as Functionssample.ps1 and called it from powershell command prompt. I have set executionpolicy to unrestricted and ran the powershell as "Administrator"

.\Functionssample.ps1 'Display-HelloWorld'

I don't see "hello world" on console.

```
    Function Display-HelloWorld
   {
         cls
       Write-Host "Hello World"

    }
```

Comment: Eric, I am calling the funcition. Please read my post. filename and function

Answer (score 3):

You've written a script with a function in it.  Since scripts can accept parameters, the call `.\functionsample.ps1 Display-HelloWorld` is simply passing "Display-HelloWorld" (a string value) as a parameter to the script.

When the script executes, it creates a function object, but the function is never called.

To execute your function, you need to dot-source the script (note the extra dot and space)

```
. .\functionsample.ps1
```

This runs the script in your current scope so that the function is available after the script is done.

Then, you can call it.

```
Display-HelloWorld
```

Answer (score 2):

Your choices are:

1) Write a script containing the function, and the code which calls it, in a file called anything - here 'testing.ps1':

```
Function Display-HelloWorld
{
    cls
    Write-Host "Hello World"
}
Display-HelloWorld

# run it
PS C:\test> .\testing.ps1
Hello World

# After it runs, the contents of the script are 'gone' from the current session.
```

2) Put the function content in a file called `functionname.ps1`. Treat the script itself as a function:

```
cls
Write-Host "Hello World"

# run it, pretending the file is a function
PS C:\test> .\Display-HelloWorld.ps1
Hello World
```

3) Put the function code in a file by any name:

```
Function Display-HelloWorld
{
    cls
    Write-Host "Hello World"
}

# dot source or Import-Module the code, to load the file contents ready for use
PS C:\test> Import-Module .\testing.ps1

# Call the function, loaded from the file
PS C:\test> Display-HelloWorld
Hello World
```

You're mixing them up - when you put `function xyz` in the file, then run the file, it runs as a script. Function is defined. Nothing calls it. Function is removed from memory. When you run the file and pass it a parameter, it's as if you're doing 2), as Mike Shepard says, passing 'Display-HelloWorld' as a string parameter to the file, as if the file itself was a function. It doesn't have a `param()` block to accept parameters, so it does nothing.

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead in your console:

```
Import-Module .\Functionssample.ps1
```

That will load your script and its functions that you have created, so you could now run them in that console. While it isn't a module, it still works for this situation...

```
Display-HelloWorld
```

Edit: My apologies, my first post had the incorrect command

Another option would be this:

```
powershell -command "& { . .\script1.ps1; Display-HelloWorld }"
```

it uses dot sourcing to run through the script and then executes the command. If you only do `.\Functionssample.ps1 Display-HelloWorld` it doesn't actually seem to be invoking the command properly. It will run without error, but it doesn't actually run the function like you're expecting it to. If a more experienced PowerShell user can give an explanation as to why that doesn't work that would be helpful for this post.

Comment: I am trying to understand why the way I am calling isn't working

Comment: I see. I don't think `.\Functionssample.ps1 Display-HelloWorld` will do anything by itself. Even though you do run the function name, it doesn't actually seem to invoke the function into running. I'll update my post with more options.